# How this guy do glow(neon) text

Tags: themes

I think everything is clear from this video.
https://vimeo.com/22798433
I am interested in how to make the text exactly like that.
Here's another example but this is vs code
https://youtu.be/cxjP4731Av8?t=111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could have a look at the [emacs-live](https://github.com/overtone/emacs-live) config used in the video, or more generally use a terminal emulator with graphic effects like [cool-retro-term](https://github.com/Swordfish90/cool-retro-term) and run emacs from a shell.

[image: glowing tezxt]